# List view Scroll doesn't work in CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter

I'm unable to resolve this issue..

I tried to use all the scroll controllers together, but it doesn't display the entire list.

If I don't use TabBarView in SliverFillRemaining, it works, but I need tab control for different pages.

```
Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        primary: true,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            toolbarHeight: kZero,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            primary: false,
            pinned: true,
            bottom: TabBar(
              controller: controller,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: LocaleKeys.profile_shares.tr()),
                Tab(text: LocaleKeys.profile_about.tr()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: controller,
              children: [
                postsWidget(),
                aboutWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

```
ListView.builder(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        // primary: false,
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 10,
        padding: LayoutConstants.maxVerticalPadding.copyWith(top: kZero),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var userData = context.read<UserContext>().userData!;
          return SizedBox(
            width: context.width,
            child: PostCard(
              post: Post()
                ..miniUserData = MiniUserData(
                  id: userData.id,
                  username: userData.username,
                  numberId: userData.numberId,
                ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

I tried many different solutions but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are encountering might be related to the `CustomScrollView's` `shrinkWrap` and `primary` properties. When you set `shrinkWrap` to `true` and `primary` to `true`, it can limit the scrolling behavior of the `CustomScrollView`. In your case, you want the content of each tab to scroll independently, so you should avoid setting these properties.

Try this

```
Scaffold(
  body: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2, 
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
        SliverAppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 0, // Hide the app bar
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          pinned: true,
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: LocaleKeys.profile_shares.tr()),
              Tab(text: LocaleKeys.profile_about.tr()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          postsWidget(),
          aboutWidget(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Certainly, can we solve this problem using CustomScrollView? Because I want to create a header at the top with SliverAppBar and use its stretch property.